# fast voltage follower (from datasheet of LM318) and current of input terminals

Tags: operational-amplifier, input-impedance

I was looking at the datasheet of LM318 and found the op-amp configuration below (first image). I think the voltage at input terminal 2 is V input.  But I wasn't able to figure out what V out is going to be.

I can figure out what the V out is going to be for the second circuit, knowing that the voltage at the negative input has to be V in and the current flowing through R1 down to GND also has to flow through R2.

Also, can input terminals of an op-amp output current? (I know that due to high input impedance, no current flows into them)

[image]
[image]

Comment: All the figures on p6 of the datasheet show the answers and reasons why.

Comment: Hint: the term "voltage follower" means a circuit where the output (at least roughly) equals the input.

Comment: What speed do you need? The 118.218.318 should have LOW input capacitance, because of cascading of the input bipolar diff pair devices. This should allow fast settling. But what is fast?